# devexpress grid don't select check box by select on row

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I Have a grid show some Rows. 
and it has a checkbox columns. 
this checkbox in some situation set enabled false and user cant select this checkbox
But when click on row checkbox it was selected.

how I Can set this property false and when user select on row this checkbox not select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
Grid.SettingBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = false;
```

you should add this code in `Page_Load()`